# How Do We Receive a Notification from Server When there is a Update in the Database in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I Am New to Notifications in iOS. My Task is to Receive Notifications from Server to My Application Whenever there is an Update in the Database.

I Searched for this one and I have Implemented Location Notification in iOS.

Can Some One Give me some steps for Receiving Notifications from Server?

Comment: database is local to the ios device, then how server come to know? You have to trigger web-service call to server then server will do something for you

Comment: are you talking about push notification or local notification?

Comment: @Rushabh Push Notification

Comment: Explain in detail about exactly what you want to?

Comment: @jayrajm.g. i am storing data in the server if there is any modification in that i have to Receive Notification.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are talking about your remote database, in which case you have to implement a push notification.

The tutorial on raywenderlich.com is bit lengthy on this subject, but covers everything you need to do, both on the app side and the server side.

Link: http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Answer (score 1):

Write a php/python script for that and put it into your web server.here a php script sample  save it with example.php and put it into your server with .pem(private key) file also replace your device token with that device token in which you want sent notification.

```
<?php

// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = '0f744707bebcf74f9b7c25d48e3358945f6aa01da5ddb387462c7eaf61bbad78';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'pushchat';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'My first push notification!';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 1):

1) you have to make code from your server side(using .net or php etc) to push the notification to APNS as per your criteria.

for push notification you need following:

> - Device token for in which phone you want to receive notification.
> - p12 file of your push notification certificate from developer.apple.com site which you generated for your particular app ( you can export p12 file from keychain by selecting your particular app push notification certificate)

2) Enable your app to receive pushnotification using below:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions {   
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:      (UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];    
     return YES; 
     }
```

3) now following method will receive push notification from your xcode when push notification aries;

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo { ...}
```

this is general scenario for pushnotification for brief description read following :

[link 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

[link 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32963/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-2)